# Event Viewer for Websphere MQ failures, errors on Unix

Tags: unix, ibm-mq, event-viewer

On Windows Server, the event viewer can provide several errors like 2035 or insufficient size of logs for transactions,...
I  don't see where i can find exactly the same events logs on unix ( Solaris & Redhat). Nothing on syslog, messages and audit.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Because the 2035 is an error returned to the application, it is not something that is logged in the QMGR error logs by default. You can however enable reporting on the 2035 so that you can troubleshoot it further yourself.  Use  [MQSAUTHERRORS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21377578) to generate a FFDC detail or use [MQS_REPORT_NOAUTH](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21299319)  to better diagnose return code 2035

Answer (score 0):

Look into queue manager specific error log files, `AMQERR01.LOG, AMQERR02.LOG` and `AMQERR03.LOG` under qmgrs/<-your qmgr name->/errors directory.

Comment: I know these errors log files. Unfortunately, we do not see the MQ error 2035.

Comment: What level of MQ are you at? I seem to recollect, MQ v701 did not log 2035 error.